SQL Query- How to fetch record if Group by value is not part of select list table
I have 2 tables similar to this
Table 1 - user table.



U_ID
STATUS
TR_CODE




1
open
NA


2
closed
SUC


3
closed
CAN


4
closed
INV


5
closed
SUC


6
closed
DEN


5
closed
NA


6
closed
DEN



Table 2 - lookup table.



LK_CD
LK_DSC




SUC
Success


CAN
Cancelled


INV
Invalid


DEN
Denied


FAIL
Failed



Now I'm trying to get the count of different TR_CODE where STATUS is closed. I need to get the relevant description of TR_CODE from table 2 and group it accordingly
I used below query
SELECT LK_DSC,count(*) as num from user u,lookup where
   LK_CD = u.TR_CODE and u.STATUS = 'closed' GROUP BY  LK_DSC

This is giving me the required data for all TR_CODE that are present in lookup table.But if it is not in lookup table it is not showing(eg: NA is not getting listed)
How to fetch that record as well if not in lookup table and show TR_CODE name itself for NA
Below is the output that Im expecting
LK_DSC     Count

Success      1
Cancelled    1
Invalid      1
Denied       2
NA           2

But with the query I used NA is not getting fetched
Any help would be appreciated

Are you sure your problem is in any way related to Javascript?

Please edit your question and show us the real output.  What you have above is a mixture of data from the LK_DSC and TR_CODE columns.

@TimBiegeleisen Updated

Use a conditional count instead of COUNT(*) and move the WHERE filter to the count expression:
SELECT
    COALESCE(l.LK_DSC, u.TR_CODE) AS LK_DSC,
    SUM(u.STATUS = 'closed') AS num
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN lookup l
    ON l.LK_CD = u.TR_CODE
GROUP BY 1;

Note also that we use a left join here so as to retain every LK_DSC even if it should have no matching records in the user table.
If you only want to report LK_DSC with a non zero close count, then add a HAVING clause assertion:
SELECT
    COALESCE(l.LK_DSC, u.TR_CODE) AS LK_DSC,
    SUM(u.STATUS = 'closed') AS num
FROM user u
LEFT JOIN lookup l
    ON l.LK_CD = u.TR_CODE
GROUP BY 1
HAVING SUM(u.STATUS = 'closed') > 0;


I need to fetch only the records with status closed count..But this way if there are any other LK_DSC in table 2(lookup) that are also showing for eg : FAILED 0 which shouldnt be the case

Also for NA it is showing as Null..But I need to show that as NA itself

Check the edited answer above.

Umm...NA will never appear in your report because you don't select that column.

My primary goal is to fetch data from table 1 (user table) and the records should have full description which are present in table 2(lookup)..Im not sure if you understand my requirement here.The query seems to be other way..Confused with usage of join here

Try the updated answer above.  The only way I can generate your expected output is to fall back to using the short form code for cases where the longer description does not appear in the second table.
